# Forwarding all htm file extensions to a a specific file

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have been given a task to change 100's of .htm files on a site to only show the contact page. As appose to changing the files I am thinking to just use a .htaccess file and force all requests which includes a ".htm" or ".html" to the contact.htm page.

I have very limited knowledge about .ht_access files and the one I have which forces all requests through a index.php isn't working because one of the rewrite conditions is to check whether the file is real or not.

Any advice or tips will greatly be appreciated:

```
 // My .htaccess rules at the moment:
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ contact.htm [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^[^\.]*\.htm$ contact.htm [NC,L]
```

This will replace everything that ends with `.htm` to contact.htm

**EDIT:** Made a mistake, checked it and fixed it

Comment: Hi Puckipedia, thank you for your answer, but it does not seem to do anything? I also turned the conditions off but the rule does not appear to do anything

Comment: Have you enabled mod_rewrite? Add this line at the top:`RewriteEngine On`

Comment: Fixed it now, checked it on apache 2 on my laptop

Comment: Haha ironically this appears to work on just 2 other pages, I checked and the url's are indeed correct (loading .htm files)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to maintain your SEO and prevent link rot (which is [bad](http://www.nngroup.com/articles/fighting-linkrot/)), you'll want to let the client know that the old HTML file is no longer valid:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^.*html?$ http://example.com/contact.html
```

**Edit:** as an interesting side note, returning a 410 [might be a more appropriate response](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E410.html).

Comment: Hey @BryanH, thank you for your advice. I am getting a permanent redirect issue, I think when it forwards to that url, it tried to forward again, causing an infinite loop, how would I exclude contact.htm?

Comment: Right you are - I wasn't paying attention! What's the address of the contact page?

Comment: Hi @BryanH, the site isn't live at the moment but the file will be contact.htm which it redirects too